# Load an OpenCV::Mat as a .pgm

Tags: opencv, mat, pgm

I have a program which loads a .PGM image file into std::vector m_data :

```
void LoadPgm( std::string const& filename ){
  std::ifstream in( filename.c_str(), std::ios::binary );
  if ( !in ){
     std::cerr << "Error in Image::LoadPgm: Could not open file " << filename << std::endl;
     std::exit(1);
  }

  std::string data = std::string( std::istreambuf_iterator< char >( in ),
                                  std::istreambuf_iterator< char >() );

  if ( ( data[0] != 'p' && data[0] != 'P' ) || data[1] != '5' ){
     std::cerr << "Error in Image::LoadPgm: Unsupported image format " << filename << std::endl;
     std::exit(1);
  }

  unsigned char const* p = reinterpret_cast< unsigned char* >(&data[2]);

  m_width  = ReadNumber( p );
  m_height = ReadNumber( p );

  if ( ReadNumber( p ) > 255 )
  {
     std::cerr << "Error in Image::LoadPgm: Unsupported image deep " 
               << filename << std::endl;
     std::exit(1);
  }

  p++;

  m_data.assign( p, p + m_width * m_height );
}
```

Where the ReadNumber() is :

```
unsigned long ReadNumber(unsigned char const*&buffer){
 do{
     if ( *(buffer++) == '#' ){
        while ( *(buffer++) != 10 );
     }

     switch (*buffer)
     {
        case   9 : 
        case  10 : 
        case  13 : 
        case ' ' : 
        case '#' :
        case '0' : 
        case '1' : 
        case '2' : 
        case '3' : 
        case '4' : 
        case '5' : 
        case '6' : 
        case '7' : 
        case '8' : 
        case '9' : break;
        default :  
        {
           std::cerr << "Error in Image::LoadPgm: invalid data" << std::endl;
           exit( 1 );
        }
     }
 } 
 while ( (*buffer < '0') || (*buffer > '9') );

 unsigned long value = 0;

 do
 {
     value = 10 * value;
     value += *(buffer++) - '0';
 } 
 while ( (*buffer>='0') && (*buffer<='9') );

 return value;
}
```

My question is how can I load, instead of .pgm file, an OpenCV Mat into m_data (without creating a file).

**EDIT**

Here is my solution (thanks to [ypnos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21974/ypnos)) :

```
void LoadPgm(cv::Mat1b &cvimg ){
    Mat1b matimage;
    cvtColor(cvimg, matimage, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    // Create a pgm object
    std::vector<unsigned char> dest(matimage.rows*matimage.cols);
    std::copy(matimage.begin(), matimage.end(), dest.begin());
    std::stringstream in;
    in << "P5"     << std::endl;
    in << matimage.cols  << std::endl;
    in << matimage.rows << std::endl;
    in << "255"    << std::endl;
    in.write( reinterpret_cast<char*>( &dest[0] ), matimage.cols * matimage.rows );

    std::string data = std::string( std::istreambuf_iterator< char >( in ), std::istreambuf_iterator< char >() );

    if ( ( data[0] != 'p' && data[0] != 'P' ) || data[1] != '5' ){
        std::cerr << "Error in Image::LoadPgm: Unsupported image format " << std::endl;
        std::exit(1);
    }

    unsigned char const* p = reinterpret_cast< unsigned char* >(&data[2]);

    m_width  = ReadNumber( p );
    m_height = ReadNumber( p );

    if ( ReadNumber( p ) > 255 ){
        std::cerr << "Error in Image::LoadPgm: Unsupported image deep" << std::endl;
        std::exit(1);
    }

    p++;

    m_data.assign( p, p + m_width * m_height );
}
```

Comment: Depending on where the matrix comes from, you would need to copy row-by-row because of stride. It is almost never a good idea to access mat.data directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reliably copy all pixels of a 1 channel unsigned char matrix into an array, do this:

```
cv::Mat1u source = …
std::vector<unsigned char> dest(source.rows*source.cols);

std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), dest.begin());
```